# CSS3 PIE background color transparency

Tags: css, background-color, css3pie

I am using CSS3 PIE for adding CSS3 Rules to IE.

http://css3pie.com/
It's great but I have a little problem now m using a semi transparent image for the background and PIE.htc automatically adds a gray background.
"background-color:Transparent;" is not working for me.

My question is this: how can I use CSS3 PIE with transparent background?

Comment: in what browser you have the problem? It would help, if you add your code here.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well the problem is that you are probably setting just the `background` property but not the generated `-pie-background` property. So, try this `-pie-background: transparent;`. Sorry, I may not be of much help because I am not familiar to CSS3 PIE.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're running into this issue: https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/12

If you have a box-shadow applied, PIE draws that shadow all the way behind the background area of the element rather than making it transparent like other browsers. So if your element's background is transparent then you will see through to the opaque shadow shape behind it. Unfortunately there is no workaround other than removing the box-shadow.